# Regex - Search for words with letters and numbers with at least 4 characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find returns such as

```
hal9
bet97
78test
```

but not

```
h4t
4444
test
h1
```

Essentially, any words with numbers and letters but with a minimum of 4 characters.

Currently I'm trying this for numbers and letters in a word

```
(?=\w*[a-z])(?=\w*[0-9])\w+
```

but I'm trying to limit it to 4+ characters only.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try `\b(?=\d*[a-z])(?=[a-z]*\d)[\da-z]{4,}\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(?=\w*[A-Za-z])(?=\w*[0-9])\w{4,}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5cC6aU/1/).

If `\w` is Unicode-aware in your regex flavor (e.g. Python `re`), use

```php
\b(?=\w*[^\W\d_])(?=\w*\d)\w{4,}\b
```

Also, if your regex flavor supports Unicode property classes and you need to check for any Unicode letter, you can use

```php
\b(?=\w*\p{L})(?=\w*\d)\w{4,}\b
```

where `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?=\w*[A-Za-z])` - after any zero or more word chars, there must be a letter
- `(?=\w*[0-9])` - after any zero or more word chars, there must be a digit
- `\w{4,}` - four or more word chars (letters, digits, connector punctuation/`_`)
- `\b` - word boundary